# Better to multiply matrices in javascript or a shader?

Tags: javascript, performance, webgl

I've been looking at several webgl examples.  Consider [MDN's tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebGL).  Their vertex shader multiplies the vertex by a perspective matrix and a world position matrix:

`gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);`

But the `uMVMatrix` is itself the product of several transforms (translation, rotation, etc) calculated in javascript with the help of some matrix libraries.

It seems like it would be faster to calculate their products directly in the shader; surely that's faster than doing it in .js.  Is there some reason why they choose this approach?

Now, I guess you can stack an arbitrary number of transforms in an arbitrary order this way, which is more flexible.  But say that flexibility isn't needed, is there any reason to avoid doing transforms directly in the shaders?   Something like

`gl_Position = uPMatrix * uRotationMatrix * uScaleMatrix * uTranslationMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);`

*e:* To add some context, in my particular case I'll only be rendering 2D rectangular entities (mostly sprites), so the number of vertices will always just be 4.

Given the overhead of bringing in a library to do fast .js matrix multiplication, seems like pushing these calculations into the shader is definitely the way to go for my personal case.

(Plus, even if it were slower in the balance than doing it in javascript, shunting the calculations into the GPU is probably worth something in and of itself!)

Comment: Well I suppose in some situations it might be faster. I think in the general case, where you've got a variable number of transforms and types of transforms per object it would be difficult to write a general purpose shader to deal with that. Also keep in mind that while the GPU is fast, it has to run its code for each vertex while your app can do it just once in JS. My own question would be don't we supply P*MV pre-multiplied to the shader? :)

Comment: Isn't the entire point of GPUs to perform transforms on multiple vertices *in parallel*?

Comment: Sure, but it only does small batches of them... like 64 at a time or something. For something you just do once, I'd think it might be faster on the CPU. I'm no expert though.

Comment: So you really want to do essentially the *same exact multiplication* over and over again in the shader??   As it is now, you have something calculating a value *once*, and this value which gets bound as a vertex attribute to be used over and over again in as many running vertex shader instances the GPU decides to fire up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it depends ....

If you do it in the shader it's done for either every vertex (vertex shader) or every pixel (fragment shader). Even a GPU does not have infinite speed so let's say you are drawing 1million vertices. It's likely 1 set of matrix math calculations in JavaScript vs 1 million matrix calculations in on the GPU, the JavaScript will win.

Of course your milage may very. Every GPU is different. Some GPUs are faster than others. Some drivers do vertex calculations on the CPU. Some CPUs are faster than others.

You can test, unfortunately since you are writing for the web you have no idea what browser the user is running, nor what CPU speed or GPU or driver etc. So, it really depends.

On top of that, passing matrices to the shader is also a non-free operation. In other words it's faster to call `gl.uniformMatrix4fv` once than the 4 times you show in your example. If you were drawing 3000 objects whether 12000 calls to `gl.uniformMatrix4fv` (4 matrices each) is significantly slower than 3000 calls (1 matrix each) is something you'd have to test.

Further, the browsers teams are working on making math through JavaScript for matrices faster and trying to get it closer to C/C++.

I guess that means there is no right answer except to test and those results will be different for every platform/browser/gpu/drivers/cpu.

Comment: Ah, given my use case the number of vertices will only be 4.  Four is a lot less than a million, so I'm pretty sure the shader will turn out faster for me.  :)

Comment: Doesn't the GPU optimize it though? If we are talking about uniform matrices, it seems to me it could precalculate them in advance, eliminating the need for calculating them for every vertex. No such thing happening?

Comment: Even if the GPU optimizes it (driver dependent) you're still passing them all once per model. 4 calls to gl.uniformMatrix4fv * 3000 models is 12000 calls vs 3000 calls if you're passing just one matrix. Test it. See what you get?

Comment: "Further, the browsers teams are working on making math through JavaScript for matrices fasters and trying to get it closer to C/C++." @gman could you give a source? Do you have any updates on this or links where I can go to check the status right now? Is it by any means at or past Numpy performance for example? Maybe I should mold this into a new question... Anyway, in case you, or anyone else who knows more about this, reads it..

Comment: I doubt it will get as fast as numpy because of limits of JS. On the other hand WebAssembly might get there and allow a numpy like library to use from JS just like numpy itself is not written in Python it's written in C and interfaced to python you could be able to do something similar interfacing a WebAssembly lib to JS. For a simple 4x4 matrix to matrix multiply [SpiderMonkey is currently 4x faster than V8](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=6363) (used to be slower). The point being it has gotten faster

Comment: Thanks! But why is Spidermonkey being faster than V8 relevant, isn't Google putting as much effort into implementing WebGL awesomeness into their browser ad Mozilla is doing into theirs? WebGL, although often presented by Brendan Eich, is supported by Microsoft and Google as well right?

Comment: And about Numpy being written in C => that's the reason why I'm asking. Is WebGL, since it has more direct control over GPU CPU etc, theoretically capable of reaching the same performance as another C library with bindings in a non-C language, like Numpy? And if it is theoretically, will this become reality in the near future?

Answer (score 2):

I think that JayC and gman got the point.

I would like to try to explain it too.

**Fact 1:**
Javascript on CPU and shader on GPU are two different things and you have to work with them with this on your mind. We have two kinds of shader in WebGL. Vertex shader and fragment shader. Vertex does set of calculations on each vertex and fragment does some set of calculation for every pixel. Shader calculations are usually much more faster then javascript.

**Fact 2:**
Each shader obtains few variables from javascript and it will use them to recalculate vertex/pixel parameters. Number of these variables is limited and each shader loop obtain same variables.

**Fact 3:**
Shader code is much more sensitive then javascript one. Cause javascript is executed once, but shader is always a loop. So if you multiplicate two numbers/matrices 4x4, javascript performance will be almoast same and you will not notice anything. But shader will do it in every loop, so one line can drop performance from ultra high to ultra low. This is what gman says.

So now **what is possible to do?** (Im not entirely sure that this is possible with webgl shaders, but I think it might be. ) Imagine that you have only few verticies. Like 3, 5 or 20, or even more, it doesnt really matter. And you want to make 100000 matrices multiplications for each vertex. So in fact you can first multiplicate all 100000 things together and then use that result to do just one multiplication with each vertex and you will get a same result as if you multiplicate each vertex 100000 times.

**How will you do that**. You will pick these 100000 matrices and assume that they are vertices. Then you will write a shader, that will multiplicate it and you will somehow obtain a result. So the multiplication will be pretty fast. And now you will write a shader, that will use a result and will work with final vertices.

**But I have to say two things.** Im not sure if one shader loop can obtain anything from another loop in webgl. One loop can work only with one vertex and it doesnt see other vertices, but I think you can use `attribute variable` to share it. We have only 2 kinds of shaders. Second is, that this task doesnt require expert mind, but genius one.

**What about performance?** Imagine that you dont want to do 100000 multiplications. You want less, like 2, 3 or 20. Then if you use a shader to do that work, you will have to use pipeline to send data to GPU and then back to CPU, wich can be slower then doing calculations in javascript.

At the end... so even if shader is used for graphic calculations, it is possible to use it in different way. But your approach must be different, conscious and resourceful, which is harder then simple javascript multiplication. Hope it helps everyone.